# Idiomatic ways to structure a function with 2 helpers in Ruby

Tags: ruby, module, namespaces, structure

I coded up a solution to the narcissistic numbers kata [on codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5287e858c6b5a9678200083c/train/ruby).

After writing a single function, I extracted two helper functions in order to keep my line count at a maximum of 5 lines ([Sandi Metz' Rules For Developers](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/sandi-metz-rules-for-developers#five-lines-per-method)).

This resulted in 3 functions:

```
def digits(number)
  number
    .to_s
    .chars
    .map(&:to_i)
end

def checksum(digits, exp)
  digits
    .map { |d| d**exp }
    .reduce(:+)
end

def narcissistic?(number)
  digits = digits(number)
  exp = digits.length
  checksum = checksum(digits, exp)
  checksum == number
end
```

Now, I would like to pretend that this code should be added to a larger real-world project. My question is how this should be idiomatically done in Ruby.

Generally speaking, I have two requirements:

1. The code should be somehow *namespaced* (considering a real-world project).
2. It should be clear that `narcissistic?` is the *public API function* - being on a *higher level*, while the other two functions `digits` and `checksum` are on a *lower level* of abstraction.

My reasoning so far is: This code does not really need OOP. But in Ruby the only way to get something into a namespace is by creating a `Class` or a `Module`.

Probably, a `Module` would be a better choice? Still, I am not sure whether I should prefer:

```
module MathUtils::NarcissisticNumbers
  def self.narcissistic?(number)
    ...
  end

  private
  ...
end
```

vs

```
module MathUtils::NarcissisticNumbers
  def narcissistic?(number)
    ...
  end

  private
  ...
end
```

How would you bring in this code into a Ruby project? Please, if you know a best-practices solution, let me know! :)

Any other pointers would be highly appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion, it's depend on the purpose of your method, consider 2 names of `narcissistic` method:

1. `narcissistic?(number)`: this make me think there's an outside class that take responsible for checking whether the input number is narcissistic or not.
2. `narcissistic?`: this make me think about the class itself be able to check that whether it's narcissistic or not.

So in case 1, let assume that you have a class `Code` that include the module `MathUtils::NarcissisticNumbers`, if that module does not support class method then only instances of the class Code `can_do` check `narcissistic`, then the method name should be fall into case 2 above.

On the other hand, if the module support class method, then the method name should fall into case 1, however, suppose you have a class `Money` that need to check `narcissistic` it's value, if you use `Code.narcissistic?(money.value)` that'll make other confuse (at least they need to know what's `Code`), but it's total make sense if you use `MathUtils::NarcissisticNumbers.narcissistic?(money.value)`, other will understand immediately that is a checking a kind of number method.

I suggest that you let `MathUtils::NarcissisticNumbers` is a `module_function` and create another module for `narcissistic?`

```rb
module MathUtils::NarcissisticNumbers
  module_function
  def is_narcissistic?(number)
  end
end

module Narcissistic
 def narcissistic?
   MathUtils::NarcissisticNumbers.is_narcissistic?(self.value)
 end
end

class Code
 include Narcissistic
end

class Money
 include Narcissistic
end

code = Code.new(...)
code.narcissistic?

# for those classes that only check narcissistic? internally
# then you can include MathUtils::NarcissisticNumbers
# since is_narcissistic?(number) become a private method

class FormatNumber
 include MathUtils::NarcissisticNumbers
 def format(number)
   if is_narcissistic?(number)
    # ...
   else
    # ...
   end
 end
end

# you can use MathUtils::NarcissisticNumbers wherever you want (as helper)
# on other classes that not include Narcissistic, including views , ...
<% if MathUtils::NarcissisticNumbers.is_narcissistic?(input) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with most things what Lam already wrote. However, I would extract a class first which you use in your module. Classes make it a much more easy to work with data (and to follow the advice your methods should be max 5LOC).

```
class MathUtils::NarcissisticNumber
  def initialize(number)
    @number = number
  end

  def valid?
    checksum == number
  end

  private
  
  attr_reader :number

  def checksum
    digits.map { |d| d**exponent }.reduce(:+)
  end

  def digits
    @digits ||= number.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i)
  end

  def exponent
    @exponent ||= digits.length
  end
end
```

By using a class we were able to remove all method parameters and temp variables. We can now use this class in a helper module suggested by Liam.

```rb
module MathUtils::NarcissisticNumbers
  def narcistic?(number)
    NarcissisticNumber.new(number).valid?
  end
end
```